# How can dynamically add a View to a ViewGroup and vertically align with one of its child

Tags: android

I have a ViewGroup and it has a few children. And one of them is a TextView ("+id/text").
In my code, I would like to know how can I add a new View or ViewGroup which will be positioned vertically aligned and below the TextView (+"id/text")?

### Thank you.

I have followed the advice below and try to use TableLayout. 
As a test, I try to layout statically to make sure things are aligned correctly.

Here is my layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/panel" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight">

    <TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_column="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"                    
            android:gravity="left" />
    </LinearLayout>
   </TableRow>
   <TableRow>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_column="1"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

But when i run in on emulator. The ImageButton on the 2nd row, does not align vertically with the textView in 1st row.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a TableLayout as your ViewGroup.  With a TableLayout you can programmatically add a child at a specific location.

```
View view = new ViewIWantToAdd();
TableLayout layout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table_layout);
layout.addView(view);
```

Would add a view at the bottom of the TableLayout.  Typically you would use a TableRow as the contents of the TableView, but you can add any view.

Comment: If I have TableLayout with 3 coloumns, can I add a child sometime to the bottom of the 1 column and then other times, add it to the bottom of 2 column?

Comment: I believe you need to add to the TableLayout a TableRow at a time.  Within your TableRow you can configure which column items end up in.  Check out the TableLayout documentation: http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html

Answer (score 1):

If your layout is not so complex, use [RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html)

> A Layout where the positions of the children can be described in
>   relation to each other or to the parent...

When you insert a new child view, create a new LayoutParams then [setRule](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#addRule(int,%20int))

You can put the child view below the textView with [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#BELOW)

:)